# for loop dice roll and textbox.Text updating troubles c#

Tags: c#, dice

I'm trying to make a program where there is at first a random dice roll that is "rolls" to decide the number of times that `dicethrow` should throw the dice (between 1 and 9 times), anything greater than rolls should be the end of the game. I also need the score to update after every roll, which is what I was trying to do in the comments, but I'm not sure if I would need to `TryParse` the `wagerTextBox.Text` to get a value and prevent format exceptions, or if it would be fine without it (or where I would put the `TryParse`).

```
#region private method randomdiceroll
private void rollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rollDice();
    wagerTextBox.Enabled = false;
}
private int RollsNumber()
{
    Random rolls = new Random();
    return rolls.Next(1, 10);
}
private int diceThrow()
{
    Random dice = new Random();
    return dice.Next(1,7);
}
private void rollDice()
{
   int i = RollsNumber();
   for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
   {
       diceThrow();
       int wager = Convert.ToInt32(wagerTextBox.Text);
       int score = wager * 100;
       scoreTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
       {
          // wagerTextBox.Text = null;
         //  wagerTextBox.Text = scoreTextBox.Text;
       }
   }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: I tried to comprehend your question and looked at your code. It makes not enough sense to find the real question. Can you restate it?

Comment: Is a for loop the best way to do this, or is it better to use some other way, and what's the best way to get the score to calculate correctly, in that it's 100 * wagertextbox.Text after each roll.

Comment: @iboshuizen sorry, sometimes knowing the right question to ask is the hardest part for me. Basically, I just need either reassurance that I'm doing it close to correctly or if I'm doing it wrong, some kind of guidance as to how to do it correctly.

Comment: Asking the right question is indeed sometimes difficult.. Now you had the time to rethink, what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue of rolling a random number of times switch this code:

```
int i = RollsNumber();
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
```

to:

```
int i;
int maxRolls = RollsNumber();
for (i = 0; i < maxRolls; i++)
{
```

for your second part of the question, I have no idea what exactly you are trying to accomplish, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The second part is kind of confusing to put into words, I'll just have to work on it on my own and ask when I can state my problem more specifically. This helps a bunch though, thanks.