# c# dice roll (i <= maxRolls)

Tags: c#

I have two issues that I'm not sure how to fix.

`diceThrow()` is supposed to randomly roll a die and come up with an answer 1-6 multiple times, but only comes up with one 1-6 answer and only does that. i.e. (6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, etc)

and for `rollDice()`, I'm not sure if I just poorly defined "`i`" or `maxRolls`, but it should be that when `i > maxRolls`, the program should end and reset.

Any advice on how to fix either of these is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
//somewhere else in code
    int maxRolls = RollsNumber();
    int throwresult = diceThrow();
    int i;
//*******************************

    private void rollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rollDice();
        wagerTextBox.Text = null;
        wagerTextBox.Text = scoreTextBox.Text;
        diceThrow();

        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(throwresult));

        if (maxRolls < i)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You got too greedy.");

           //reset the form

        }
    }
    // Decides the maximum number of rolls before the player loses
    static public int RollsNumber()
     {
        Random rolls = new Random();
        return rolls.Next(1, 10);

    }
    // Throws the dice
    static public int diceThrow()
    {
        Random dice = new Random();
       return dice.Next(1, 7);
    }
    private void rollDice()
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= maxRolls; i++)
        {

                int wager = Convert.ToInt32(wagerTextBox.Text);


                int score = wager * 100;


                scoreTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(score);



        }  
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Don't create a new Random. Read the Random documentation as to why. Please search for the real issue **"[C#] duplicate random"** to find many SO duplicates. -1 to encourage use of the search feature.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, thanks!

Comment: Continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168977/for-loop-dice-roll-and-textbox-text-updating-troubles-c-sharp

Comment: @pst any idea on the second portion of my problem? maxRolls still seems to not be relating to i whatsoever.

Comment: @SethE I suspect `i` is not what it is expected to be. Note that the last `i++` is run *after* the last execution of loop. Use the Debugger to step through the code and inspect the values. (It's a dirty global variable in context.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same seed with the Random.

As msdn states  in [Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new instance of Random.

A simple way in your case is to not create new Random each time.

```
 // Throws the dice
static Random diceRandom = new Random();
static public int diceThrow()
{
   return diceRandom .Next(1, 7);
}
```

Comment: To get this to work, I changed the first line (because it wouldn't work as is) to `public static Random diceRandom = new Random();` but it's still seeding the same,am I moving in the wrong direction?

Comment: Also, any idea on the second portion of my problem? maxRolls still seems to not be relating to i whatsoever.

Comment: @SethE what is i? Since it is never set will be always be 0.

Comment: I should be the current roll number and should always be increasing by 1 after every `rollButton` press.

Comment: are you sure you want to check maxRolls < i to reset?

Comment: I believe so. Say maxRolls = 9, on the 10th roll, it should reset.